# Skyrim reinstalling it with all the mods

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

My Skyrim is slowed down because of this virus infestation called chromesearch. This hogged my computer resources tremendously and slowed It down raising temperatures to 60 sometimes 70 degrees Celsius. I managed to delete it, it seems and even the corrupted files but my Skyrim is still facing these issues which it was facing back then. 
1) Delayed shockwave reaction when dragon lands nearby. My player takes up to 2 or more seconds to respond to the shockwave created by the dragon when landing. 
2) Turning into a werewolf also isn't instantaneous and takes some time to initiate. 
3) Undressing takes similarly long to(Either for sex or for breastfeeding via jugs).

now here is my problem. I have a lot of mods on NMM , some from steam workshop and some I have directly pasted into the game files. so now that it seems my skyrim is corrupted and malfunctioning I am thinking of uninstalling and reinstalling it. How do I Keep all the mods that I Love while getting the game back to it's functional self.

Keep in mind other games like witcher3 and Arkham Knight work just fine so problem is still with Skyrim.

Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a mod manager, this is easy.  Uninstalling Skyrim doesn't remove the mods you've downloaded; it only removes the copy of them that is installed into your Skyrim folder.  If you use NMM, just go down the list of mods you have with a green check next to them, right click and choose "uninstall from active profile", then install them again as usual.

It is unlikely that Skyrim is actually infected.  It makes a poor target for malware, because mods can shift pointers away from its native files.  If your security software doesn't detect a problem in the Skyrim files, particularly during a [boot scan](https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785), the problem is most likely in a Windows process.   Skyrim is very heavy on even modern computers, due to its extensive scripting engine and calculation of things that happen when you aren't there for them to happen (such as new enemy spawning, quest progress, and movement of NPCs).  It also puts a lot of hooks into your input, so anything which lags your input even the smallest amount can be affected by an errant process gobbling CPU resources. I had a similar issue very recently due to an infection on a drive that I pulled from a  dubious computer; it caused my mouse to lag every 15 seconds and made outfit swaps very slow.

That means that as long as the virus is present anywhere on the system, you can expect the same performance problems, even on a clean install of Skyrim.   I recommend making a boot disc or USB key of one of the pieces of software listed in the link above and doing a full, deep scan of your computer before Windows boots.  Try to repair the actual problem, because the infection won't just go away if you reinstall things.  It's more likely to infect things as you install them.

Also, as a side note, recommend you keep your questions PG-rated, since a lot of people using StackExchange are using it from the workplace. No need to get into the deets on your LoversLab mods...

Comment: Hello CDove, thanks for answering!! You are right I already did a clean OS Install. This has however deleted the firmware drivers and utility that came with it. I am going to Install them now.. Just have to figure out the order in which to Install them.... sorry for the delayed response and Thanks Again!!!